# scrolling search results to center of screen in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editors, scite

Typically in Microsoft Word if a search result is off the page, the document window will move down to display the result, already selected - but only just barely showing it. Is there a way to make the display move more, so that the result is (for example) centered instead?  This is possible in other text editors such as SciTE using

```
caret.policy.yslop=1
caret.policy.lines=5
```

Comment: I find this a problem with Internet Explorer also (on the very rare occasion I use it).

Comment: No-one found a solution to this yet?